# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que cada row de una tabla de la BD se elimine 24h despues de que se creó? Al igual que WhatsApp

Tags: mysql, nodejs

Uso Nodejs y mysql. La idea es mostrar en mi web contenido durante 24 horas.
Intento implementar una subasta y quiero ponerle una duracion de 24 horas.

```
CREATE TABLE subastas(
    id_subasta INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_vendedor INT(11) NOT NULL,
    id_comprador INT(11),
    titulo VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    descripcion VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    provincia VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    tema VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    precio INT(10) NOT NULL,
    fecha timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_subasta),
    CONSTRAINT cf_user FOREIGN KEY (id_vendedor) REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

Uno de mis intentos fue usar un evento pero no me funciona.

```
DELIMITER $$
 
CREATE EVENT e_hourly
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 MINUTE
    DO
    BEGIN
      DELETE FROM subastas WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`fecha`) < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-120000); /*probe con 2 min y no me funciona*/
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

No tengo mucha experiencia

Comment: y que has investigado y/o intentado?? Por favor haz el [tour] y lee [ask]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Porque borrar?? porque no solo poner un timestamp y leer solo lo que este hasta 24 horas antes??? ademas, si borras, perdes trazabilidad.. no deberias andar borrando cosas asi porque si.. en tal caso pone un flag de terminado....